# ${project.artifactId} in parent pom.xml resolves odd

Tags: maven

I have a bulk full of projects which have the same URLs in their pom.xml:

```
<url>https://github.com/malkusch/${project.artifactId}</url>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/malkusch/${project.artifactId}.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:malkusch/${project.artifactId}.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/malkusch/${project.artifactId}</url>
</scm>

<issueManagement>
    <system>github</system>
    <url>https://github.com/malkusch/${project.artifactId}/issues</url>
</issueManagement>
```

So I thought it's a great idea to put that into a [parent pom.xml](https://github.com/malkusch/oss-parent/blob/master/pom.xml). But the effective pom produces odd ${project.artifactId}:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>de.malkusch.parent</groupId>
  <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<groupId>de.malkusch.localized</groupId>
<artifactId>localized</artifactId>
<url>https://github.com/malkusch/localized/localized</url>
<scm>
  <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/malkusch/localized.git/localized</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:malkusch/localized.git/localized</developerConnection>
  <url>https://github.com/malkusch/localized/localized</url>
</scm>
<issueManagement>
  <system>github</system>
  <url>https://github.com/malkusch/localized/issues</url>
</issueManagement>
```

You notice that only issueManagement.url was resolved correctly. The others are totally strange, especially **${project.artifactId}.git** -> **localized.git/localized**. I'm using Maven 3.0.4. Am I using some undefined feature? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this behaviour is confusing.

Perhaps the easiest way to understand this is to consider how Maven itself is built. It's in Subversion, and the reactor poms (the poms with `<modules>` sections) tend to also be the parent poms of the modules themselves.

```
project/pom.xml (artifactId: parent)
|-+ module1/pom.xml (artifactId: module1, inherits parent)
|-+ module2/pom.xml (artifactId: module2, inherits parent)
```

Here, the parent pom (project/pom.xml) contains a `<modules>` section, and is also inherited by module1 and module2.

Now suppose the SCM URL for parent is `svn://host/path/project/`: what should maven do so that you don't have to specify the SCM URL again in the two modules?

Well, the SCM URL for module1 is `svn://host/path/project/module1`, and Maven can compute that by adding the artifactId to the SCM URL it inherits from the parent pom. It simply needs to append the artifactId to the SCM URL. So that's exactly what it does.

So that's the behaviour you're seeing:

**${project.artifactId}.git** becomes **localized.git/localized** as follows:

```
localized  -> from ${project.artifactId} in the inherited SCM URL
.git       -> from the the inherited SCM URL
/localized -> from adding the artifactId to the inherited SCM URL
```

You will see this behaviour in the SCM URLs, and (I think) for `project.url` and the URL in `distributionMangement.site.url`. However, Maven doesn't assume that the `issueManagement` URL structure follows your directory structure, which is why you see it inherited correctly.

Comment: Wow! Is this behaviour documented? I'm quiet impressed by that context sensitivity of ${project.artifactId}.

Comment: There seem like quite a few issues in the Maven JIRA, which suggests a lot of confusion about this behaviour. This comment by Jörg Schaible provides the best explanation of the behaviour I can find: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2290?focusedCommentId=103845#comment-103845

Comment: yes, everything is documented: that's result of model building, see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-model-builder/

Answer (score 1):

> Since Maven 3.6.1, inheritance can avoid appending any path to parent value by setting model attribute value to false for each url

src : [maven-model-builder](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-model-builder/)

You need to append following properties to SCM tag in your POM :
`<scm child.scm.connection.inherit.append.path="false" child.scm.developerConnection.inherit.append.path="false" child.scm.url.inherit.append.path="false">...</scm>`

It seems IntelliJ shows error, but at then end, it does the job perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the already great background information given, in order to still deploy with a valid `scm url`, [since Maven 3.5](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.2/maven-model-builder/) you can correct the "module" name that gets appended per the `project.directory` property:

```
<properties>
    <project.directory>${project.artifactId}</project.directory>
</properties>
```

And then you just simplify your `developerConnection` to not include the `artifactId` anymore since it will be appended as the `project.directory`:

```
<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@server:</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

Assuming this doesn't conflict with any other `goals`, that should allow a `deploy` goal to do its job with the correct git url for a non-multi-module Maven project where you've defined the `scm.developerConnection` in the parent pom.

When I run a `deploy`, I see maven doing a correct push like:

```
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /projectDir/proj && git push git@server:proj master:master
```